# Android mp android chart set type face for XAxisLeft

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart, android-typeface

I have a line chart using the library **MPAndroidChart**

```
    mChart.setData(data);
                        mChart.getAxisLeft().setTypeface(MyApplication.giloryItaly);
                        mChart.invalidate();

                        mChart.getXAxis().setTypeface(MyApplication.giloryItaly);
                        mChart.getAxisRight().setTypeface(MyApplication.giloryItaly);
```

The problem is the `AxisLeft` font value cannot be changed even when using

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setTypeface(MyApplication.giloryItaly);
```

but works well for `XAxis`

Any solution **how to change font type** for `AxisLeft` and `AxisRight?`

Comment: And if you use `getYAxis()` instead of `getAxisLeft()` ?

Comment: There is no getYAxis in the lineChart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In you `linechart`, Use

```
LineChart horizontalPChartLine = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.horizontalPChartLine);
        XAxis xAxis = horizontalPChartLine.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setTypeface(tf);
        xAxis.setTextSize(12f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        xAxis.setEnabled(true);
```

please check [Styling / modifying the axis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis#styling--modifying-the-axis)

Answer (score 1):

```
Paint p = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
p.setTextSize(...);
p.setColor(...);
p.setTypeface(...);
```